# InfluxDB query and filter values

Tags: influxdb

cant seem to find if similar post.
I am using Grafana / InfluxDB I am trying to create a variable in Grafana, to create this variable I need to query values which I can do easily with this piece:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "name"
```

However, I need to filter the values that I get, in example, I would like only to see values that have specific url maybe just https://google.com.

I tried something like this

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "name" WHERE "name" = 'https://google.com'
```

And I get only on instance of this URL, perhaps there is a way to find all the URL's which contain https://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [regular expressions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#regular-expressions), probably:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "name" 
WHERE "name" =~ /.https:\/\/google\.com./
```